# How do I fix the container for rows in one position?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an item container in which the title, date, and status are arranged in order on one line, set by the following:

```
.title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Below that is a description. Accordingly, there can be many such containers. But if their statuses are different (in my case, "In Progress" and "Done" => the width of the block changes), and as a result, the date line shifts in each column.

I need to make it so that the date is fixed and even, regardless of the status.
[image: [Click to see result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3hpr.png)]

(Here is a link to a CodePen example)

https://codepen.io/fiorgf/pen/QWJggzM

I can set flex-basis for the status div block, but it will again be fixed like this (according to my codepen)

```
<div class="status">
     <span>In Progress</span>
</div>
```

```
.status {
 flex-basis: 66px;
 text-align: right;
}
```

As far as I understand, it's bad practice to set pixels for flex-basis.

Comment: A font-size relative unit would probably be preferable to a value in pixels - but you will have to define flex-basis resp. width here, if you want to achieve your desired result. Your elements here do not have any kind of relation to each other that would make them "adapt" to the widest value, like f.e. a table column would.